# Deno permissions issue - Uncaught PermissionDenied: network access

Tags: deno

I'm trying out [Deno](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/first_steps#a-simple-tcp-server) and while running an example, I ran into error:

```sh
$ deno run https://deno.land/std/examples/curl.ts https://example.com
Download https://deno.land/std/examples/curl.ts
Warning Implicitly using master branch https://deno.land/std/examples/curl.ts
Compile https://deno.land/std/examples/curl.ts
error: Uncaught PermissionDenied: network access to "https://example.com/", run again with the --allow-net flag
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendAsync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:98:10)
    at async fetch ($deno$/web/fetch.ts:591:27)
    at async https://deno.land/std/examples/curl.ts:3:13
```

I've tried doing

```
$ deno run https://deno.land/std/examples/curl.ts https://example.com --allow-net
```

but still get the same error. What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--allow-net` flag has to be **after `deno run` and before the file name**, not appended at the end.

```sh
deno run --allow-net https://deno.land/std/examples/curl.ts https://example.com
```

Read more about [Deno permissions here](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/permissions).

Answer (score 0):

```
--allow-env                    
    Allow environment access

--allow-hrtime                 
    Allow high resolution time measurement

--allow-net=<allow-net>        
    Allow network access

--allow-plugin                 
    Allow loading plugins

--allow-read=<allow-read>      
    Allow file system read access

--allow-run                    
    Allow running subprocesses

--allow-write=<allow-write>    
    Allow file system write access
```

example

```
    deno run --allow-net app.ts //give a network permission

    deno run --allow-all app.ts //give an all permission
```

Answer (score 0):

> **[Deno](https://deno.land/)** is a runtime which is secure by default. This means you need to explicitly give programs the permission to do certain
>   'privileged' actions, such as access the network.

Make use of `--allow-net=<domain>` permission flag: in your case `deno run --allow-net=example.com https://deno.land/std/examples/curl.ts https://example.com`

If you don't provide **domain name** it will allow for all domains which can be again a security compromise. See here [Permission](https://deno.land/std/permissions/mod.ts#L16).