# How to solve Deno error: Uncaught PermissionDenied

Tags: deno

when run an application using `deno run app.ts` command and its give an `error: Uncaught PermissionDenied`

```
error: Uncaught PermissionDenied: access to environment variables, run again with the --allow-env flag
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendSync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:72:10)
    at Object.toObject ($deno$/ops/os.ts:33:12)
    at file:///opt//deno/app.ts:5:22
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deno - Uncaught PermissionDenied: network access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847371/deno-uncaught-permissiondenied-network-access)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of issue we need to set a flag when run application

diffrent kind of permmistions

```
--allow-env                    
    Allow environment access

--allow-hrtime                 
    Allow high resolution time measurement

--allow-net=<allow-net>        
    Allow network access

--allow-plugin                 
    Allow loading plugins

--allow-read=<allow-read>      
    Allow file system read access

--allow-run                    
    Allow running subprocesses

--allow-write=<allow-write>    
    Allow file system write access
    deno run -allow-all app.ts
```

Example

```
  //Give an environment permission
  deno run --allow-env app.ts

  //Give an all permission 
  deno run -allow-all app.ts 
  OR
  deno run -A app.ts
```

Ref link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61878925/9077019

Answer (score 1):

In your console log, the error caused by trying to access [environment variables](https://deno.land/x/dotenv/README.md), in Deno you have to provide/grant the permission flags to be able to access the environment variables:

If you are reading envirnoment variables directly from the terminal:

```
> TEST=123 deno --allow-env app.ts
```

If you are reading envirnoment variables from .env file:

```
> TEST=123 deno --allow-env --allow-read app.ts
```

**NOTE**: always priorities [least privilege principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) and don't grant all permissions arbitrary to the app.